# rails method(sym) application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have come across this method in reading some metaprogramming articles.

here is the example and application based on following link:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-method

```
class Demo
  def initialize(n)
    @iv = n
  end

 def hello()
   "Hello, @iv = #{@iv}"
  end
 end

k = Demo.new(99)
m = k.method(:hello)
m.call   #=> "Hello, @iv = 99"

l = Demo.new('Fred')
m = l.method("hello")
m.call   #=> "Hello, @iv = Fred"
```

i am able to execute code below as well:

```
k = Demo.new(99)
m = k.hello
#=> "Hello, @iv = 99"

l = Demo.new('Fred')
m = l.hello
#=> "Hello, @iv = Fred"
```

so my question is, what is the point for the method() step?
just to simplify it?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is purely educational - its a pretty simple example.

`.method` lets you fetch the [method object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html) for a method attached to any object.

This can for example be used to inspect where the method is defined:

```
irb(main):002:0> User.method(:find).source_location
=> ["/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/core.rb", 157]
```

Or the owner which declares the method:

```
irb(main):017:0> User.method(:find).owner
=> ActiveRecord::Core::ClassMethods
```

Or you can use it to pass the method around as a callback:

```
class Foo
  def and_then_do(callback)
    "Hello "
    callback.call
  end

  def say_hello
    "World"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.and_then_do(foo.method(:say_hello))
```

The key point here is that unlike many other languages methods in Ruby are objects and `method` gives you the method object which can be inspected.

This also is an example of the difference between call and send which both can be used for dynamic calling:

```
mn = :hello

k = Demo.new(99)
m = k.method(mn)
m.call

k = Demo.new(99)
m = k.send(mn)
```

Send is called on the object itself while call is called on the method object.